# "Failed authorization procedure" when trying to add SSL certificate to site

Tags: security, nginx, ssl

When I ran this command in my digital ocean server:

`sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path /home/james/postr --installer nginx -d <sitename>`

I get this error:

```
Failed authorization procedure

The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from 
http://www.<sitename>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oAVGa4eBNfQQ1Vrn_q-
iKjV2T6ue3H5kOcxEWpztrHc

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.venvor.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.<sitename>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oAVGa4eBNfQQ1Vrn_q-
   iKjV2T6ue3H5kOcxEWpztrHc:
   "<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL
   /.well-known/acme-challenge/oAVGa4eBNfQQ1Vrn_q-iKjV2T6ue3H5kOcxEWpztrHc
   was not found on "
```

I already tried adding the url path to my urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^.well-known/acme-challenge/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

However it still doesn't work. Any idea what the problem is?

**EDIT:**

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/postr`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name venvor.com www.venvor.com 174.138.62.249;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/james/postr;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/james/postr/draft1.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured location block in your nginx conf file to allow access to those ACME challenge files?

Comment: No I haven't - could you tell me what exactly I add to my location block? I've added my current config file in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the below location block to your nginx configuration file :

```
location ^~ /.well-known {
root /your_path_to/document_root;
allow all;
}
```

**How it works :**

- The Let’s Encrypt verification server will look for verification
  files created by the client in a subdir of your docroot ( .well-known). This means that these files must be publicly accessible.
- In the above location block "^~" modifier does the non-regular expression match. For instance, it could handle requests for /.well-known/acme-challenge/dkaslf_kfjadlkso^kfds-fkdssjl .
- **allow all** directive grants the public access to the specified folder.

Please refer : https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works.

Comment: Thankyou! This works the site(s) are now HTTPS. Can you please explain exactly how your code is working in the Nginx config file? Also I chose:
`2: Redirect - Make all requests redirect to secure HTTPS access` - can you tell me the implications of this?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: And on selecting Redirect option, all your insecure http requests will be redirected to secured requests now.